# Microsoft Graph/Teams-is there a way to list a user's channels using delegated permissions?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to convert some bot logic to use delegated permissions instead of application ones, but I'm running into an issue with a bot feature that can post to a Teams channel from a 1:1 conversation.  The user can ask the bot to post to a channel, and this works fine, but when I take away Group.ReadWrite.All, I can't find a workaround that doesn't require admin consent.  Here's the current flow:

- Get the user's joined teams (me/joinedTeams-gets the user's joined Teams. This requires **Team.ReadBasic.All**.
- Get the channels in the team (/teams/{id}/channels).  This requires **Group.Read.All** (admin consent)
- Post to the channel (/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages) which requires **ChannelMessage.Send**

So with delegated, non-admin permissions, I can list a user's teams, post a message to a channel on their behalf, but not list the channels on their joined teams?  The docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) say that you need delegated Group.Read.All or ReadWrite.All, both of which require admin consent.

Is there another way that I'm missing to get a list of teams/channels for a user to cross-post to?  I don't want to have to add the bot to the channel.  I suppose I could create/store a list of connectors for each channel, but that's a lot of extra user overhead. The challenge is that I want to deploy this bot to an org that refuses to give any application/admin consent permissions to 3p apps.

Comment: To List channels using Graph API you will need team id That requires above mentioned permissions.

Comment: I can get the Team ID with Team.ReadBasic though, but even with the team ID, I can't find a way to get the channel list without an admin-consented permission.

Comment: You need to provide admin consent for this API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how I missed this, but there's a Channel.ReadBasic.All permission that doesn't require admin consent.  This means I can do something like this in my bot:

- Get a user's joined teams with graphClient.Users[aadUserId].JoinedTeams.Request().GetAsync()
- Get the team's channels with graphClient.Teams[teamID].Channels.Request().GetAsync()
- Post to the channel as outlined in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) with c.Teams[teamID].Channels[channelID].Messages.Request().AddAsync(chatMessage).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

The only difference here is that the message is attributed to the user and not the bot, but as long as that's OK, this is a way to have a user initiated cross-post from a bot to a Team.